# Call one method with parent class instead of two with childs

Tags: c#

I have classes:

```
public class Throw
{
    public double speed { get; set; }

    public double accurency { get; set; }
}
public class FastThrow : Throw{}

public class LowThrow : Throw{}
```

Instead of having:

```
public static FastThrow SetFastThrow(List<object> args)
{
    return new FastThrow
    {
        speed = (double)args[0],
        accurency = (double)args[1]
    };
}

public static LowThrow SetLowThrow(List<object> args)
{
    return new LowThrow
    {
        speed = (double)args[0],
        accurency = (double)args[1]
    };
}
```

I want to have one with parent class:

```
public static Throw SetThrow(List<object> args)
{
    return new Throw
    {
        speed = (double)args[0],
        accurency = (double)args[1]
    };
}
```

To declare list or some other generic interface with child class with instance of parent class. Then adding new elements to existing collection. I know that below example has compilation errors, but it should look like:

```
List<List<object>> firstList = new List<List<object>>();
public void Main()
{
    IList<FastThrow> secondList = new List<Throw>();

    foreach (var item in firstList)
    {
        secondList.Add(SetThrow(item));
    }
}
```

I read about contravariance and do not know if this is possible.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Your base class `SetThrow` method will *always* return an instance of `Throw`, never `FastThrow` or `LowThrow`. And no, a `List<Throw>` isn't an `IList<FastThrow>` - there's no guarantee that every item in a `List<Throw>` is a `FastThrow`, and in your case it certainly wouldn't be. Nor can you add a `Throw` to an `IList<FastThrow>`. Please talk about what you're trying to achieve rather than just the code you've got so far.

Comment: Do you want a `public static T SetThrow<T>(List<double> args) where T : Throw, new()`? It will return `FastThrow` or `LowThrow` depending on the type `T` specified. `T` must be `FastThrow` to `return` a `FastThrow` `object` ...

Comment: `IList<T>` is not contravariant. It's not even close. It derives from `IEnumerable<T>`, which is actually *co*variant. You should start thinking in the domain of the problem that you are trying to solve, not only focus on the technical solution. This is called the XY problem.

Comment: If your question is whether you can add `Throw` instances into `List<FastThrow>`, the short answer is no.  And it's not a good idea to consider in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. **Rahter than**

> To declare list or some other generic interface with **child** class with
>   instance of **parent** class.

you **should**

> To declare list or some other generic interface with **parent** class with
>   instance of **chidlren** class.

The second way, as Anirban said, use generic classes, refactor your `SetThrow` method as following:

```
    public static T SetThrow<T>(List<object> args) where T : Throw, new()
    {
        return new T
        {
            speed = (double)args[0],
            accurency = (double)args[1]
        };
    }
```

So that you can use `SetThrow` method only to generate different kinds of classes as long as they are child classes. e.g:

```
 IList<FastThrow> secondList = new List<FastThrow>();

            foreach (var item in firstList)
            {
                secondList.Add(SetThrow<FastThrow>(item));
            }
```

And generic classes are strong typed and elegant to use.